# Using jQuery.animate() to interpolate CSS rules

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate, interpolation

I'd like to automatically apply a "gradient" CSS style to a series of `<div>` elements; i.e. setting the `opaque` rule on a sequence of elements ranging from transparent to fully opaque.

`jQuery.animate()` seems to do a great job at interpolating CSS styles like I need. But, obviously, `animate()` transitions over time, whereas I'd just like to calculate a number of individual "frames".

Somewhere in the jQuery code must be hidden the code that calculates these individual steps for the animation functionality. I was expecting to encounter something like `interpolate(objectWithOldCss, objectWithNewCss, step)` but can't seem to find anything like that.

Is there any way to access jQuery's code that interpolates CSS rules and use it directly?

---

Edit: Thanks to James Montagne's answer, I ended up with the following `jQuery.interpolate()` method:

```
$.fn.interpolate = function(name, value, blend, easing) {
    var elem = this[0];
    if (jQuery.isArray(name)) {
        $.Tween(elem, {duration: 1}, name, value, easing || "linear").run(blend);
    } else {    
        easing = blend;
        blend = value;        
        $.each(name, function(n, v) {
            $.Tween(elem, {duration: 1}, n, v, easing || "linear").run(blend);
        });
    }
}
```

It's demonstrated here: http://jsfiddle.net/mwvdlee/yfcg5/

Comment: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.9-stable/src/effects.js  In particular, have a look at the `run` method of `Tween`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery uses `Tween( elem, options, prop, end, easing )` to calculate the `tween` values.  It cannot calculate all of them up front because there is no way to know exactly when each step will run.  Because of this, it gets the next value at the time the step executes based on the % of duration that has passed.

Note: You must include a duration (any duration) or else it will ignore easing.

For your `opacity` example, you could do something like this:

```
var $divs = $("#holder div");
var steps = $divs.length;
var tween = new $.Tween( $divs[0], {duration: 1}, "opacity", 0, "swing");

for(var i = 0; i < steps; i++){
    var val = tween.run(1/(steps-1)*i).now;
    $divs.eq(i).css("opacity",val);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/878QQ/3/

This uses the opacity of the first matched div as the start point and 0 as the end.

Comment: Excellent answer!
I had to tweak it in order to make it work with colors as well (requires jQueryUI), then I just made a new function of it; `jQuery.interpolate` so it could handle an object with multiple properties at once: http://jsfiddle.net/mwvdlee/yfcg5/